# is criterion of eliminability and criterion of non creativity independent

Tags: logic

In introduction to logic by Patrick suppes, in Theory of definition 2 criteria are given, criterion of eliminability and criterion of non creativity. 
So if any formula is eliminable it should also be non creative and vice versa?
is this true? 
[image]

Comment: Could you quote the definitions (with enough context for them to make sense)? That would give readers  who don't have your book an opportunity to answer you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notions of eliminability and conservativeness are necessary conditions for one theory to be a "definitional extension" of another.

Suppose you have two theories, $T$ and $T_1$, such that the vocabulary of $T_1$ includes the vocabulary of $T$, and everything provable in $T$ is provable in $T_1$.

Informally, "eliminability" means that $T_1$ can paraphrase its fancy jargon into the basic terms of $T$.  More precisely, $T_1$ satisfies the *eliminability* criterion with respect to $T$ provided that for every formula $\phi$ in the language of $T_1$, there's a formula $\psi$ in the language of $T$ such that $T_1\vdash \phi\leftrightarrow \psi$.

"Conservativeness" means that $T_1$ doesn't tell us anything about the subject-matter of $T$ which $T$ didn't tell us already.  More precisely, $T_1$ satisfies the *conservativeness* criterion with respect to $T$ provided that for every formula $\phi$ in the language of $T$, if $T_1\vdash \phi$ then $T\vdash \phi$.

The two criteria are not equivalent.  In one direction, let $T$ be a theory with the one axiom "Canada is large", and let $T_1$ be a theory with the one axiom "Canada is large, and Egypt is ancient".  Then, $T_1$ proves nothing about Canada in the language of $T$ which $T$ doesn't prove already, but $T_1$ cannot prove that the sentence "Egypt is large" is equivalent to any statement couched with just "Canada" and "large".  Thus, $T_1$ satisfies conservativeness but not eliminability.

Conversely, if $T$ is as before, and $T_1$ is axiomatized by "Canada is large, something is large iff it is cold, but not everything is cold", then $T_1$ satisfies eliminability but not conservativeness. Or more trivially: if $T$ is consistent but $T_1$ is inconsistent, then $T_1$ satisfies eliminability but not conservativeness.