# Can definitions of Operators and Relations lead to Contradictions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Operators and relation definitions are important in mathematics but could some definitions be inconsistent, leading to a contradiction either syntax wise and/or semantically? If so, is there any examples of relations and operators leading to a contradiction as a result of of being improperly defined?

Comment: What do you mean about *definitions* being inconsistent? We run into problems if we allow things to be defined in terms of each other, since what we're really doing is implicitly claiming that a certain "relational equation" has a unique solution, but as long as our definitions are "well-founded" there's no way a problem can arise since they're really just a series of *abbreviations*.

Comment: I mean, that follow our definitions, a contradiction could arise if our operators and relations are improperly defined.

Comment: See criterion-of-eliminability-and-criterion-of-non-creativity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298909/is-criterion-of-eliminability-and-criterion-of-non-creativity-independent).

Comment: A famous definition that leads to a contradiction is "Curry's Paradox".  Define $S$ as the proposition "If this is true, then Y".  Classically that is equivalent to $S \iff (S \to Y)$, which by truth tables implies $Y$ (but also does so constructively).

Comment: Ah, okay, so definitions can lead to contradictions just as axioms. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If we're sloppy about how we make definitions, we can run into problems; but these problems emerge when our "definitions" implicitly make *mathematical claims* which are unjustified or even false.

Let's look at the case of defining a specific object - say, a function. When we say something like

> "We define *foo* to be the function that *blahs*,"

we're really saying the following:

> "There is a single function that *blahs*; we call this "*foo*.""

The second half of this claim is completely unproblematic; we're just giving a name to something. Really, we're just introducing an abbreviation. It's the **first part** that's a potential source of trouble. We're making two claims:

- *Existence*: There **is some** function that *blahs*.
- *Uniqueness*: There **are no two distinct** functions that *blah*.

Either of these claims could be incorrect. A definition needs to be preceded by proofs of existence and uniqueness. These proofs are often trivial and therefore omitted, but they're important.

---

OK, let's see some examples of bad definitions of objects.

- "The set of all things which are not in this set." Here we have the implicit claim $$\mbox{"There is a unique set $S$ such that for all $x$, $x\in S\iff x\not\in S$."}$$ The *existence* part of this claim is clearly false, so we don't even need to talk about the *uniqueness* part. *(Note that this is different from, and sillier than, [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).)*
- "The function that sends a real number $r$ to its seventh decimal digit." This is an interesting example, since there's a "depth-two" implicit claim: that "its seventh decimal digit" makes sense! This corresponds to the fact that our definition uses a phrase which needs defining, namely "its seventh decimal digit," so before we even start to talk about the whole function we need to think about decimals. The "depth-two" implicit claim is $$\mbox{"Every real number has a unique seventh decimal digit."}$$ The *existence* part of this is true, since every real number has a decimal expansion, but the *uniqueness* part fails since some real numbers have multiple decimal expansions: is the seventh decimal digit of $1$ the digit $0$ or the digit $9$? We could of course fix this by specifying that "the decimal expansion" disallows ones with trailing nines, but **as written** this is problematic.

On the other hand, here's a neat example of a definition which looks circular **but is perfectly valid**:

- "The set of all objects which are in this set if and only if they are not in this set."

Here I'm claiming $$\mbox{"There is a unique set $S$ such that for all $x$, $x\in S$ if and only if $(x\in S\iff x\not\in S)$."}$$ It's a good exercise to check that $(i)$ the emptyset has this property, and $(ii)$ no other set has this property. So **self-referentiality does *not* immediately lead to invalidity!** Psychologically, however, it's easier for us to see and be suspicious of the unique-existence-claim implicit in a self-referential definition than in a general definition.