# Predicates and mathematical objects

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, predicate-logic, foundations, simplex

I'm reflecting about mathematical objects as numbers, sets/classes, graphs and so on.

Any class correspond to a predicate in one variable and any graph correspond to a predicate in two variables. There are exceptions for the correspondence in the other direction since "$x\notin x$" doesn't correspond to a class and "$R(x,y)\leftrightarrow \neg R(y,y)$" normally doesn't correspond to a graph.

In my opinion it seems to exist possible mathematical objects for each $n$ and predicates $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ with similar semi-correspondence. My intuition about this is that these objects are built upon the idea of simplex and I would like to know if it is true that

> It always exists predicates $p_1,\dots,p_{n}$ such that
>   $p(x_1,\dots,x_n)\leftrightarrow\wedge_{i=1}^{n}p_i(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots,x_n)$

Comment: Assuming you're working in ZFC, the class corresponding with $x \not\in x$ is the class $V$ of all sets, since $x \not\in x$ is true for all sets $x$. A class is (externally) the extension of a unary predicate, i.e. an (external) equivalence class of the (external) relation of provable equivalence, so in that sense every unary predicate corresponds to a class. (Likewise for graphs and binary predicates, I suppose, depending on what you mean by 'graph'.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before addressing your actual question, let me point out that there are serious issues with your motivating examples.

First of all, "$x\not\in x$" *does* correspond to a class - namely, the universal class (in ZFC at least; a smaller class under NF). Every formula defines a class; that's what classes are, really.

Meanwhile, the issue with the $R$ you describe is that you haven't really *(but see the bulletpoint below)* defined a relation, but rather written a property a relation may or may not have. That's the issue with a self-referential "definition" (note that $R$ occurs on both sides of the expression you've written: when defining an object you need to show that it $(1)$ holds of something and $(2)$ only holds of one thing, and you haven't done that. *Actually, this is something you have to do with **any** purported definition, but self-reference in particular makes $(1)$ especially nontrivial.* (See also my old answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2798407/28111).)

- Interestingly, your property *does* pin down a unique relation on a unique domain (= set of "vertices"): setting $x=y$ shows that we can't have any vertices at all, and there's only one binary relation on the emptyset. However, that probably wasn't intended, and indeed you would generally *also* have to define the domain of the graph. So when I said above that you haven't really defined a relation, what I really meant was that you haven't *shown that you have* defined a relation.

---

These issues, however, don't actually impact your question (although they probably do impact its motivation).

Your question has an easy negative answer: let $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ hold iff for some $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ we have $x_i=0$. Then for any tuple of objects $a_1,...,a_n$ we have $$p(0,a_2,a_3,...,a_n)\wedge p(a_1,0,a_3,...,a_n)\wedge...\wedge p(a_1,a_2,..., 0).$$ So the desired $p_i$s would have to satisfy $$p_1(a_2,a_3,...,a_n)\wedge p_2(a_1,a_3,...,a_n)\wedge ...\wedge p_n(a_1,a_2,..., a_{n-1})$$ **for every tuple of objects $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$**. But then we have $$\bigwedge_{i\in\{1,...,n\}}p_i(a_1,..., a_{i-1}, a_{i+1}, ..., a_n)$$ **for every tuple of objects $a_1,..., a_n$**, which is a problem since e.g. $\neg p(1,1,...,1)$.

Incidentally, it's easy to see that the only *possible* candidate $p_i$s, for a given $p$, are $$p_i(a_1,..., a_{n-1})\iff \exists b(p_i(a_1, a_2,..., a_{i-1}, b, a_i, ..., a_n)).$$